# Alphabetically sorted results into (prior) STUFF command

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a list of IDs and a list of names

```
ID  Names
1   Apple;Zebra;Boy
2   Dog;Balloon;Mall
3   Phone;TV;Computer;Lamp
```

Names is multi-delimited. I want to have these values permanently sorted Alphabetically. (The back story is I will Hash these values for duplicate detection so the sort matters, but that is not important right now).

My idea was I was going to use a Split Strings function and write to a temp table with a sort order. Then use the STUFF command to bring it all back together.

Problem is the sort order doesn't stick from my temp table. The Stuff command is not sorted.

Is there a better way to do this. Or how can I modify Stuff to sort the delimited values?

Desired output:

```
ID  Names
 1  Apple;Boy;Zebra
 2  Balloon;Dog;Mall
 3  Computer;Lamp;Phone;TV
```

I'm using SQL Server 2019 (v15.0.2000).

```
SELECT * FROM names --imported table

--Create SplitStrings function
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings
(
    @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number),
        Item FROM (SELECT Number, Item = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
        CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)))
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
        FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS APPLY sys.all_objects) AS n(Number)
    WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
        AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, 1) = @Delimiter
    ) AS y);
GO


--Sort and add to temp table

  SELECT s.[ID], f.Item as Names-- INTO #names
  FROM names AS s --TABLE NAME
  CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings(s.[Names], ';') as f ORDER BY ID ASC, Names ASC;

 SELECT * FROM #names ---not sorted
 
 --Stuff names back sorted

SELECT [ID]
     ,(STUFF((SELECT CAST('; ' + [Names] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
         FROM dbo.#names two
         WHERE two.[ID] = one.[ID] 
         FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '')) AS Sorted_Names
--INTO [#Sortednames] --Filename of new table
FROM dbo.#names one GROUP BY [ID]
```

But this does not work.

Comment: The real answer will depend on the version of SQL Server

Comment: If you are on sql 2017 or greater string_agg should work in place of stuff.

Comment: Should be SQL Server 15.0.2000

Comment: **Don't store lists in columns!** This schema design cries out for an additional table.

Comment: FYI, `STUFF` isn't aggregating your data, `FOR XML PATH` is; all `STUFF` is doing is removing the first 2 characters from a string. Though, if you're on SQL Server 2019, why are you not using `STRING_AGG`?

Comment: FYI, 15.0.2000 is the RTM version of 2019; you should really install the CUs; there were multiple bug fixes in the early ones.

Comment: You original code was pretty close. You just needed to add order by in the FOR XML-part to get it to sort your final values. Since sql server doesn't guarantee sorting otherwise

Comment: You don't need to sort the names to detect duplicates if instead of hashing the whole string, you sum the hash of each word.

Answer (score 5):

Since SQL Server 2017, you can use [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

As you have SQL Server 2019, you can use it:

```
CREATE TABLE names
(
    [ID] int, 
    [Names] varchar(22)
);
    
INSERT INTO names
    ([ID], [Names])
VALUES
    (1, 'Apple;Zebra;Boy'),
    (2, 'Dog;Balloon;Mall'),
    (3, 'Phone;TV;Computer;Lamp');

-- Create SplitStrings function
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings
(
    @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number),
        Item FROM (SELECT Number, Item = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
        CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)))
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
        FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS APPLY sys.all_objects) AS n(Number)
    WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
        AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, 1) = @Delimiter
    ) AS y);
```

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT s.[ID], f.Item AS Names-- INTO #names
    FROM names AS s --TABLE NAME
    CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings(s.[Names], ';') AS f
)
SELECT 
    ID, STRING_AGG (Names, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Names ASC)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ID
```

| ID | (No column name) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple;Boy;Zebra |
| 2 | Balloon;Dog;Mall |
| 3 | Computer;Lamp;Phone;TV |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-o0Wpl6a)

As Martin Smith pointed out there is also a function build in for [splitting strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) since SQL Server 2016, so there is no need for the split function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT s.[ID], f.value as Names-- INTO #names
    FROM names AS s --TABLE NAME
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(s.[Names], ';') AS f 
)
SELECT 
    ID, 
    STRING_AGG (Names, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Names ASC)
FROM 
    CTE
GROUP BY 
    ID
```

| ID | (No column name) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple;Boy;Zebra |
| 2 | Balloon;Dog;Mall |
| 3 | Computer;Lamp;Phone;TV |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RIXzaVm9)